# Filebeat failed connect to backoff?

Tags: docker-compose, logstash, filebeat

I have 2 servers A and B. When I run filebeat by docker-compose on the server A it's working well. But on the server B I have the following error:

```
pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash_ip:5044)): dial tcp logstash_ip:5044: connect: no route to host
```

So I think I missed some config on the server B. So how can I figure out my problem and fix them.

**[Edited]** Add `filebeat.yml` and `docker-compose`

**Notice:** I ran filebeat on the server A and got failed, so I tested it on the server B and it is still working. So I guess I have some problems with server config

1. `filebeat.yml`

```
logging.level: error
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0644

filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /usr/share/filebeat/mylog/**/*.log
    processors:
      - decode_json_fields:
          fields: ['message']
          target: 'json'

output.logstash:
  hosts: ['logstash_ip:5044']
  console.pretty: true

processors:
  - add_docker_metadata:
      host: 'unix:///host_docker/docker.sock'
```

2. `docker-compose`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  filebeat:
    user: root
    container_name: filebeat
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.9.3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/host_docker/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker:/host_docker/var/lib/docker
      - ./logs/progress:/usr/share/filebeat/mylog
      - ./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:z
    command: ['--strict.perms=false']
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    network_mode: bridge
    deploy:
      mode: global
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '10m'
        max-file: '50'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just guess but it seems that filebeat is not propagated to network between servers. Please share your docker-compose configuration :)

Comment: @Facty I've added the `filebeat.yml` and `docker-compose`. Notice that, I ran filebeat on the server A and got failed, so I tested it on the server B and it is still working. So I guess I have some problems with server config

Comment: One more thing: Is server A & B in docker swarm or another orchestration?

Comment: @Facty No, I don't use docker-swarm

Comment: @leminhnguyen did u figured out any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Mentioned docker-compose file is for filebeat "concentration" server
  which is running in docker on server B.
- Both server are running in same network space and/or are accessible between themselves
- Server B as filebeat server have correct firewall setting to accept connection on port 5044 (check with telnet from server A after starting container)

`docker-compose` (assuming server B)

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  filebeat:
    user: root
    container_name: filebeat
    ports:             ##################
      - 5044:5044      # <- see open port
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.9.3
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/host_docker/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker:/host_docker/var/lib/docker
      - ./logs/progress:/usr/share/filebeat/mylog
      - ./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:z
    command: ['--strict.perms=false']
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    network_mode: bridge
    deploy:
      mode: global
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '10m'
        max-file: '50'
```

`filebeat.yml` (assuming both servers)

```
logging.level: error
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0644

filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /usr/share/filebeat/mylog/**/*.log
    processors:
      - decode_json_fields:
          fields: ['message']
          target: 'json'

output.logstash:
  hosts: ['<SERVER-B-IP>:5044']  ## <- see server IP
  console.pretty: true

processors:
  - add_docker_metadata:
      host: 'unix:///host_docker/docker.sock'
```